# Chrome Extension - Obtaining Active Tab's DOM information through background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I know there have been many questions related to this topic but none of them thus far have allowed me to figure this out in V3. When I run the following background.js, I only get undefined.

The goal of my extension, at least for this stage, is to scrape the active tab's DOM and extract the text content of all of the div elements.

My background.js page:

```
function getDOM() {
    let htmlarr = [];
    const pageDOM = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (i = 0; i < pageDOM.length; i++) {
        htmlarr += pageDOM.innerHTML;
    }
    return Object.assign({}, htmlarr)
}

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(activeInfo => {

    let domRes = chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: activeInfo.tabId },
        func: getDOM
    })
    console.log(domRes);
});
```

my manifest.json:

```
    {
        "name": "HTML Sourcer",
        "description": "Extract HTML source code",
        "version": "1.0",
        "minimum_chrome_version": "10.0",
        "manifest_version": 3,
        "permissions": ["scripting", "tabs", "activeTab"],
        "host_permissions": [
            "*://*/*"
        ],
        "background": {
            "service_worker": "background.js"
        }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Problem 1

Per the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/) this API method returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) when there's no callback parameter.

To get the value of the Promise, add [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) and mark the function as `async`:

```js
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(async info => {

  let domRes = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: info.tabId},
    func: getDOM,
  }).catch(console.error);
  if (!domRes) return;

  console.log(domRes);
});
```

There's a `catch` because some tabs don't support injection e.g. the start tab or `chrome://` tabs.

##### Problem 2

In JavaScript `+=` doesn't work with arrays, but only with numbers/strings.   Use htmlarr.[push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) instead. There's also no need to convert the array to an object via Object.assign.

Actually, let's rewrite getDOM using [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
function getDOM() {
  return Array.from(
    document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
    el => el.innerHTML
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped with the response object. However, domRes[0].result still returns continuous 'undefined' . Unsure if it's because the getDOM function isn't actually reading the document, but I don't know what's causing that.

Comment: There were mistakes in your getDOM, see the updated answer.